# How to localize Grails Domain Fields

Tags: grails, internationalization

I have different Grails Domains that I want to localize. Example:

```
class MyDomainEntity {
    def name
    def description
}
```

I want that to be localized the fields `name` and `description`. What is a good way of doing this? I also need a solution which works well with Database Migration.

I found an old Grails plugin [i18n Fields](https://grails.org/plugin/i18n-fields) which seems to be outdated.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: Why do you think the i18n fields plugin is outdated? It works very well for what it does. Addressing your specific problem.

Comment: Does it work well with Database Migration?

Comment: I don't know, but you could always try and evaluate it to see if it "works well" for what you need.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore does it work with Grails 3.* ?

Comment: I don't know. Did you try it? Did it work the way you wanted it to? That's the best way to find out.